# Logic in SQL Server to create a derived column based on comparing two comma separated columns

Tags: sql-server

Want to create logic in SQL Server to create a derived column based on comparing two comma-separated columns.

Sample table data -

```
Create table ##table1 (ID INT Identity Primary Key, FulfillmentChannelStatus varchar(255),RoleAlternateSourcingChannel varchar (255))
insert into ##table1 values ('Filled,Open,In-process','Internal,Recruiter,Contractor')
  ,('Open,In-process,New','Contractor,Internal,Recruiter')
  ,('New,Filled','Contractor,Recruiter ')
  ,('Filled','Recruiter')
  ,('Open,New,Filled','Internal,Recruiter,Contractor')
  ,('Filled,Filled,Filled','Internal,Contractor,Recruiter')
  ,('Open ,Filled, In-proces','Contractor,Internal,Recruiter')
  ,('Filled','Others')
  ,('Cancelled,Filled','Contractor,Recruiter')
  ,('Cancelled, Filled, Cancel - In Process','Contractor,Recruiter,Internal')
```

> Logic for new column--

```
--select * from @@tble
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ','
SELECT 
    [Role Id],[RoleAlternateSourcingChannel],[FulfillmentChannelStatus] , [Filled fulfil] = x.value('(/root/r[sql:column("t.pos")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') 
into ##temp FROM @@tble 

CROSS APPLY (SELECT x = TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE([FulfillmentChannelStatus], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML) 
      .query('
      for $x in /root/r[text()="Filled"][1]
      return count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
      ').value('text()[1]','INT')) AS t(pos)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE([RoleAlternateSourcingChannel], @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t2(x)
```

**Scenario**: I have two comma-separated columns

1 . I need to calculate values for only **"Filled"** values (in column [Role Alternate Sourcing Channel])
2. In  1st first row-  I have a Filled value for Internal Scheduling in column ([RoleAlternateSourcingChannel])  so in the output column – it will be Internal.
3. In  2nd row – I don’t have any Filled so the output will be Null.
4. in  3rd row - I have a Filled value for Recruiter so the output will be Recruiter.

- And so on…
  5.In Row 6 for all value is filled so the output will be a recruiter. because preference of Recruiter>Internal>Contractor

6. Other than Recruiter/Internal/ Contractor all filled values will be Null.

The position of `Filled` value is not fixed. It can be anywhere such as - either at 1st place/position or 2nd place or in 3rd place.

**Expected Output -**

```
    |+----+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+
    | ID |FulfillmentChannelStatus|RoleAlternateSourcingChannel| Filled fulfil |
    +----+------------------------+----------------------------+---------------+
    |  1 | Filled,Open,In-process | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Internal   |
    |  2 | Open,In-process,New    | Contractor,Internal,Recruiter | NULL       |
    |  3 | New,Filled             | Contractor,Recruiter          | Recruiter  |
    |  4 | Filled                 | Recruiter                     | Recruiter  |
    |  5 | Open,New,Filled        | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Contractor |
    |  6 | Filled,Filled,Filled   | Internal,Contractor,Recruiter | Recruiter  |
    |  7 | Open ,Filled, In-process| Contractor,Internal,Recruiter |  Internal |
    |  8 | Filled                   | Others                       | Null      
 |   9 |  Cancelled, Filled, Cancel - In Procecess|Contractor,Internal,Recruiter |  Internal
| 10|  Cancelled, Filled| Internal,Recruiter|   Recruiter
    +----+------------------------+-------+--------+----------------------------+

**Question:** I tried Query2, For all other cases it is working fine now but for Row 9 and 10 O/P is Null but it should be Internal and Recruiter respectively.
```

Comment: *"comma-separated columns"* this is a design flaw unto itself. You *need* to fix this and normalise your design.

Comment: **There are 6 lac+ records in the table"* what does this mean? Tables don't have records, they have columns and rows, and a single column in a single row has a value. What is a lac+?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: @Larnu - 6 lac means 6 million rows in the table. For "comma-separated columns", this is how the table stores these two columns as per requirement.

Comment: Then please say that, @HawfinchTaylor . "Lac" isn't an English word, and when I googled the word I could only find "lakh" (meaning 100,000 in Indian dialect) which also should not be used on the site. (See [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379252))

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky- I tried using the Split function and switch case, but the output is not expected what I need . I am using SQL Server 2018.

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2018, @HawfinchTaylor . There were releases in 2017 and 2019, but not in 2018.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal reproducible example ##1-4 is not provided.

Shooting from the hip.

Please try the following solution based on XQuery.

XML and XQuery data model is based on *ordered sequences*, exactly what we need.

You moved the goalposts in the middle of the game.

1. I made just the "Recruiter","Internal","Contractor" as a legitimate
   values for the *RoleAlternateSourcingChannel* column. Everything
   else is filtered out.
2. I don't see any easy way to handle the preference of
   Recruiter>Internal>Contractor for the row #6.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FulfillmentChannelStatus VARCHAR(255), RoleAlternateSourcingChannel VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FulfillmentChannelStatus, RoleAlternateSourcingChannel) VALUES
('Filled,Open,In-process', 'Internal,Recruiter,Contractor'),
('Open,In-process,New', 'Contractor,Internal,Recruiter'),
('New,Filled', 'Contractor,Recruiter'),
('Filled', 'Recruiter'),
('Open,New,Filled', 'Internal,Recruiter,Contractor'),
('Filled,Filled,Filled', 'Internal,Contractor,Recruiter'),
('Open,Filled,In-process', 'Contractor,Internal,Recruiter'),
('Filled', 'Others');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

SELECT tbl.*
    , Result = x.value('(/root/r[sql:column("t.pos")]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT x = TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(FulfillmentChannelStatus, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
      .query('
      if (count(/root/r[text()="Filled"]) eq 1) then
          for $x in /root/r[text()="Filled"]
          return count(root/r[. << $x]) + 1
      else ()
      ').value('text()[1]','INT')) AS t(pos)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(RoleAlternateSourcingChannel, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('<root>
      {
        for $x in /root/r[text()=("Recruiter","Internal","Contractor")]
        return $x
      }
      </root>
      ')) AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
| ID | FulfillmentChannelStatus | RoleAlternateSourcingChannel  |   Result   |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | Filled,Open,In-process   | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Internal   |
|  2 | Open,In-process,New      | Contractor,Internal,Recruiter | NULL       |
|  3 | New,Filled               | Contractor,Recruiter          | Recruiter  |
|  4 | Filled                   | Recruiter                     | Recruiter  |
|  5 | Open,New,Filled          | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Contractor |
|  6 | Filled,Filled,Filled     | Internal,Contractor,Recruiter | NULL       |
|  7 | Open,Filled,In-process   | Contractor,Internal,Recruiter | Internal   |
|  8 | Filled                   | Others                        | NULL       |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
```

**SQL #2**

[DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b56abcb153551abfbeb52f44097fd728)

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FulfillmentChannelStatus VARCHAR(255), RoleAlternateSourcingChannel VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FulfillmentChannelStatus, RoleAlternateSourcingChannel) VALUES
('Filled,Open,In-process', 'Internal,Recruiter,Contractor'),
('Open,In-process,New', 'Contractor,Internal,Recruiter'),
('New,Filled', 'Contractor,Recruiter'),
('Filled', 'Recruiter'),
('Open,New,Filled', 'Internal,Recruiter,Contractor'),
('Filled,Filled,Filled', 'Internal,Contractor,Recruiter'),
('Open,Filled,In-process', 'Contractor,Internal,Recruiter'),
('Filled', 'Others'),
('Cancelled,Filled','Contractor,Recruiter'),
('Cancelled, Filled, Cancel - In Process','Contractor,Recruiter,Internal');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = ',';

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, x
    FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root>' + 
          '<source><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(FulfillmentChannelStatus,SPACE(1),''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></source>' + 
          '<target><r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(REPLACE(RoleAlternateSourcingChannel,SPACE(1),''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
            ']]></r></target>' + 
          '</root>' AS XML).query('<root>
    {
        for $x in /root/source/r
        let $pos := count(root/source/r[. << $x]) + 1
        return <r>
            <s>{data($x)}</s><t>{data(/root/target/r[$pos])}</t>
        </r>
    }
    </root>')) AS t(x)
), cte AS 
(
    SELECT ID
        , c.value('(s/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS source
        , c.value('(t/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS [target]

    FROM rs
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/root/r') AS t(c)
), cte2 AS 
(
    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 
                CASE [target]
                    WHEN 'Recruiter' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Internal' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Contractor' THEN 3
                END) AS seq
    FROM cte
    WHERE source = 'Filled'
        AND [target] IN ('Recruiter','Internal','Contractor')
)
SELECT t.*
    , c.[target] --, c.seq
FROM @tbl AS t 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cte2 AS c ON c.ID = t.ID
WHERE c.seq = 1 OR c.seq is NULL
ORDER BY t.ID;
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
| ID |        FulfillmentChannelStatus        | RoleAlternateSourcingChannel  |   target   |
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
|  1 | Filled,Open,In-process                 | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Internal   |
|  2 | Open,In-process,New                    | Contractor,Internal,Recruiter | NULL       |
|  3 | New,Filled                             | Contractor,Recruiter          | Recruiter  |
|  4 | Filled                                 | Recruiter                     | Recruiter  |
|  5 | Open,New,Filled                        | Internal,Recruiter,Contractor | Contractor |
|  6 | Filled,Filled,Filled                   | Internal,Contractor,Recruiter | Recruiter  |
|  7 | Open,Filled,In-process                 | Contractor,Internal,Recruiter | Internal   |
|  8 | Filled                                 | Others                        | NULL       |
|  9 | Cancelled,Filled                       | Contractor,Recruiter          | Recruiter  |
| 10 | Cancelled, Filled, Cancel - In Process | Contractor,Recruiter,Internal | Recruiter  |
+----+----------------------------------------+-------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: One additional requirement is there that if in column 1 we have closed values for A and B both  then in result it should be A. I.e. A>B>C like this

Comment: I adjusted the answer. Check it out.

Comment: I tried using the same logic which you suggested. but for some records, the result is not correct. I am pasting the query which I tried as the Answer, as it is too big to add in the comment section. Please have a review

Comment: Now you understand importance of the **minimal reproducible example**. I already asked for it in the initial comments. Please edit your original question, and provide ##1-4. And delete your "answer".

Comment: I have edited my query.Please improvise the logic.

Comment: #1 is still missing.

Comment: -- Added sample data.

Comment: Please try **SQL #2**

Comment: (1) Don't use comments for T-SQL. (2) I took your #1 DDL and sample data population from the initial question. And SQL #2 is working with it. (3) Any update for DDL and sample data, so modify the initial question.

Comment: You need to copy SQL #2 to SSMS as-is, and run it there.

Comment: I added a db fiddle link just below the **SQL #2** label.

Comment: I have updated my query.Thanks for help.

Comment: You added some spaces to the row #10. I adjusted the answer to handle them. Check it out.